# Why does setCellPadding() and setCellPaddings() change the margin of Write()?

Tags: tcpdf

In my opinion the `setCellPadding()` and `setCellPaddings()` should only impact the margin around `Cell()` and `MultiCell()`.

How come it also impacts `Write()` and `WriteHtml()`?

Is it a feature or a bug? I don't find any information about this in [TCPDF documentation](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a374b24751bf76e4ca5ba7694f87ec2c1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `write` method, the simplest answer is that the `write` method creates cells.  It automates the text wrapping and each line is it's own cell.  It does temporarily set cell padding to 0 in `firstline` mode however.  Given how much code is dedicated to handling padding in the `write` method, the behavior with `write` is probably intended.

HTML handling is harder to say with certainty, but there is code in `WriteHTML` for handling cell padding.  I believe cell padding having an effect on HTML output is intended.  That said, there are probably cases where the HTML engine doesn't handle the cell padding in expected ways. Those cases would be likely bugs.